How to set an icon for a MacOS system network extension in VPN settings?
I am developing a macOS application that creates VPN tunnels using a system network extension (packet-tunnel-provider-systemextension). But for some reason, in the system settings, in the VPN tab, an empty icon is displayed, but the application itself has the required icon. How can I fix this?

Creating a separate asset for the network extension with an app icon and specifying it in the build settings did not help.

I haven't written a packet-filter for macOS, but I have for iOS, and the system uses the icon of the enclosing app.  I would assume the same for macOS.
